# Firebase push notifications are not vibrating the phone

Tags: android

My notification channel:

```
    CharSequence name = mApplication.getString(R.string.notification_messages_channel);
    String description = mApplication.getString(R.string.notification_messages_channel_description);
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_MESSAGES, name, importance);
    channel.setDescription(description);
    channel.enableVibration(true);
    channel.enableLights(true);
    channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{500,100,500});
    NotificationManager notificationManager = mApplication.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
```

And this is my payload:

```
var message = {
    data: {
        user: "asdasd",
        body: "adsadasd",
        sentto: "asdasd",
        gcm_username: "asdda"
    },
    android: {
        priority: 'high',
        notification: {
            title: 'Yeni mesaj aldınız',
            body: 'size bir mesaj gönderdi',
            tag: "asd223",
            sound: 'default'
        }
    },
    token: deviceToken
};
```

When a notification arrives to the phone, it plays the notification sound but not vibrating. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Channel looks set up correctly.
Try adding this directly to `NotificationCompat.Builder()`

```
val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx, "ID")
                    .setVibrate(arrayOf(100L, 200L).toLongArray())
```

And make sure, you have your phone set to: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer. I added channel information to payload and problem resolved.

New payload:

```
var message = {
    data: {
        user: "asdasd",
        body: "adsadasd",
        sentto: "asdasd",
        gcm_username: "asdda"
    },
    android: {
        priority: 'high',
        notification: {
            title: 'Yeni mesaj aldınız',
            body: 'size bir mesaj gönderdi',
            tag: "asd223",
            sound: 'default',
            channel: 'messages'
        }
    },
    token: deviceToken
}
```